# Freeze after read() 2 times using opencv4 videocapture object on the raspberry pi

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, raspberry-pi3, video-capture

Freeze after read() 2 times using opencv4 videocapture object on the raspberry pi.

details:

```
 - Raspberrypi Jessie
 - python 2.7 + opencv 4 
 - python code can be run on windows10 (py2.7 and opencv4) without problem
```

here is the code based on example:

```
import cv2
ret, frame = cap.read()
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
countDown = 20
while(countDown > 0 ):

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print countDown , "readed"
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # cv2.imwrite (  "test" + str(countDown) +   ".png" , gray )
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    countDown -= 1 

cap.release()
```

result :

```
20 readed
19 readed
then hangs forever........
```

Comment: When you say it hangs forever, is it freezing or exiting the while loop?

Comment: freezing .. without exit the loop

Comment: Can you try adding in print statements before an after each line in your while loop and showing which is the last statement that gets executed before the freeze? I can't rerun it atm so I can determine where excatly the code is freezing at step 18 - also a best practice with freezing loops.

Comment: Uh, and where is this `cv2.imread` you keep mentioning? The code you show uses a `VideoCapture` object to read grab frames from a camera...

Comment: is there a reason why you initialize frame with cap.read and set cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) in the next line of code?

Comment: I tried to add print statements to each line, the result is it can be print before "ret, frame = cap.read()", and it didn't print after it. so i think its stuck at cap.read(). Is there any chance a memory issue about raspberry pi.

Comment: sorry @DanMašek it's not cv2.imread, I changed the title to  video capture object.